# Can you have line breaks in a CSS value?

Tags: css, syntax

(Posting here because I couldn't find an answer and figured it out by experimentation, in case anyone else has this question.)

Note: Not exactly a duplicate of [Single-line vs multi-line CSS formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399262/single-line-vs-multi-line-css-formatting), because that was wondering if each property should be on its own line or if all properties for a given selector should be on the same line. I was wondering if there could be line breaks *inside* a property's value.

If you have a long value for a CSS property (for example, if you have a long list of fallback fonts for the `font-family` property), can you format that list nicely with linebreaks or will that break things?

For example, if you have

```
body {
    font-family: fontA, fontB, fontC, fontD, fontE, fontF, fontG, ..., fontZ;
}
```

can you do

```
body {
    font-family: fontA,
                 fontB,
                 fontC,
                 ...,
                 fontZ;
}
```

?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Single-line vs multi-line CSS formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399262/single-line-vs-multi-line-css-formatting)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, I'm serious. If you use linebreaks for formatting in a language like python, you can break your code. If you do it in HTML, you'll end up with teeny bits of extra whitespace you weren't anticipating. Javascript doesn't care at all. Moral of the story, different languages have different behaviors around this, so it seemed a valid thing to ask.

Comment: it's not about Python here, it's about CSS ... i know all the languages are not the same, that's why here we deal with tags and each question is specific ;) ... so within the CSS world we never had any issue with space/line-break and this is known --> you don't know about CSS minification ? i guess you do

Comment: And... I didn't know how CSS behaved, so I wondered. And figured it out. And left a record for anyone else who might be wondering. If you already know, that's great. I didn't.

Comment: Why not just try something on your own before asking here, it's a very simple experiment to run.

Comment: @JGallardo If you read the very first line of my post... I did. Thought this might be helpful for someone else in the future, as it would have been for me, so I posted it. My apologies for trying to pay it forward.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use line breaks in CSS to make it easier to read and make changes later on. By using line breaks you won't experience any weird spaces in your visuals and it will not break your generated code. This is out of the ordinary compared to other coding languages like HTML.

Answer (score -1):

The answer appears to be yes. Nothing errors out, nothing breaks.